# How to locate element by text in selenium webdriver for angularJs application

Tags: angularjs, selenium-webdriver

Below is my DOM.

```
<div class="clickable ng-binding ng-scope" ng-click="controller.selectElement(tab, detail)" ng-class="{active:(detail===(tab.selectedElement || (tab.selectedElements && tab.selectedElements[detail.property])))}" ng-repeat="detail in tab.selectedSource.detail | orderBy:'title'">
<!-- ngIf: tab.label ==='Table Data' -->
                                    City                                 
</div>
```

Can anyone tell me how to locate element in xpath by text for the above DOM. I'm specific to locate element by text because the text between the tags are only thing which is unique.

I Tried Below Xpath.

```
//div[contains(text(),'City')], 

//div[text()='City']
```

Please advice.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `.` instead of `text()` as below :-

```
//div[contains(.,'City')]
```

or

```
//div[normalize-space(.) = 'City']
```

Hope it helps...:)

Comment: @sudheendranPL you welcome..Glad to help you..Please accept the answer by click on check mark beside the answer if it helped..http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work..:)

Comment: Accepted :) Thank you.:)